# The skill's help prompt does not keep the skill session open. How to solve this issue while publishing an alexa skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

***The skill's help prompt does not keep the skill session open.*** 
How to solve this issue while publishing an Alexa skill?

Comment: See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for ideas about what kind of questions can be made and how to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Its not an issue but this is how it meant to work.

If alexa had allowed to keep the session opened for unlimited time, it would lead to misuse as people will keep session open always to listen what users are saying without their attention.

However, you have total of 16 seconds to get the input from user.
In your alexa response, if you set shouldEndSession as false then alexa will listen to get user input for 8 seconds.
If in addition to shouldEndSession you specified reprompt, then it reprompt the user the given string and again wait for 8 seconds.

So, you have 16 seconds in total.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `shouldEndSession` to `false`. I do it as follows:

```
var handlers = {
    // ...
    'AMAZON.HelpIntent': function () {
        this.emit(':tell', "Help message.");
        this.response.shouldEndSession = false;
    }
};
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
    alexa.appId = APP_ID;
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
};
```